# My site just started distorting out of no where but only on chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

All of a sudden my site started distorting on chrome mut safari, and mozilla are fine. when I look at the console I get this error

```
Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience.
```

and in my terminal it says this

```
[26/Feb/2016 01:50:19] "GET /static/posts/js/jquery.bootstrap-autohidingnavbar.js?_=1456469408048 HTTP/1.1" 200 5979. Why is this happening?
```

Comment: Looks like there's a deprecated function in the new Google Chrome update. I guess the auto hiding navbar has a detrimental effect to the end user's experience. Try changing your javascript code around. Maybe put it in the head or all the way at the bottom...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are probably using a synchronous ajax request.

If you run

```
$.ajax({async:false,url:"http://www.google.com"});
```

on chrome, you will get the same warning.

You have to remove the `async: false` options to prevent this warning from happening.

So you are probably sending a request in a synchronous way, which is a bad idea, because it blocks the main javascript thread, making the page unresponsive. Hence the warning.

PS: The log on your "terminal", is i think unrelated, because from what i've read [here](https://github.com/istvan-ujjmeszaros/bootstrap-autohidingnavbar/blob/master/src/jquery.bootstrap-autohidingnavbar.js), the `jquery.bootstrap-autohidingnavbar` is not using ajax at all.

Comment: How canI change it if I'm using a cdn?

Comment: As i said, you will have to make an audit of your javascript looking for ajax calls made with the async: true param, then switch to a callback style for handling of asynchronous responses.

Comment: All of a sudden It just started working. It had to be a google error. I adjusted nothing in my code. After a whole day damn near of searching for how to fix this it corrected itself. Thanks for the responses and I apologize to the admin for an off topic question. thanks